# Webdriver-IO test start with time costing onPrepare hook

Tags: cucumber, webdriver-io

I have this automation test running on my local.
But every time when the test is executed, there is a onPrepare hook takes 3 to 8 minutes randomly.

Here is my config.js

```
exports.config = {
//
// ====================
// Runner Configuration
// ====================
//
// WebdriverIO allows it to run your tests in arbitrary locations (e.g. locally or
// on a remote machine).
runner: 'local',
//
// ==================
// Specify Test Files
// ==================
// Define which test specs should run. The pattern is relative to the directory
// from which `wdio` was called.
//
// The specs are defined as an array of spec files (optionally using wildcards
// that will be expanded). The test for each spec file will be run in a separate
// worker process. In order to have a group of spec files run in the same worker
// process simply enclose them in an array within the specs array.
//
// If you are calling `wdio` from an NPM script (see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script),
// then the current working directory is where your `package.json` resides, so `wdio`
// will be called from there.
//
headless: true,
specs: [
    './features/logintrainer.feature'
],
// Patterns to exclude.
exclude: [
    // 'path/to/excluded/files'
],
//
// ============
// Capabilities
// ============
// Define your capabilities here. WebdriverIO can run multiple capabilities at the same
// time. Depending on the number of capabilities, WebdriverIO launches several test
// sessions. Within your capabilities you can overwrite the spec and exclude options in
// order to group specific specs to a specific capability.
//
// First, you can define how many instances should be started at the same time. Let's
// say you have 3 different capabilities (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari) and you have
// set maxInstances to 1; wdio will spawn 3 processes. Therefore, if you have 10 spec
// files and you set maxInstances to 10, all spec files will get tested at the same time
// and 30 processes will get spawned. The property handles how many capabilities
// from the same test should run tests.
//
maxInstances: 10,
//
// If you have trouble getting all important capabilities together, check out the
// Sauce Labs platform configurator - a great tool to configure your capabilities:
// https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/platforms-configurator
//
capabilities: [{

    // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
    // grid with only 5 firefox instances available you can make sure that not more than
    // 5 instances get started at a time.
    maxInstances: 5,
    //
    browserName: 'chrome',
    acceptInsecureCerts: true
    // 'goog:chromeOptions': {
    //     // to run chrome headless the following flags are required
    //     // (see https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)
    //     args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu'],
    //     }
    // If outputDir is provided WebdriverIO can capture driver session logs
    // it is possible to configure which logTypes to include/exclude.
    // excludeDriverLogs: ['*'], // pass '*' to exclude all driver session logs
    // excludeDriverLogs: ['bugreport', 'server'],
}],
//
// ===================
// Test Configurations
// ===================
// Define all options that are relevant for the WebdriverIO instance here
//
// Level of logging verbosity: trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent
logLevel: 'info',
//
// Set specific log levels per logger
// loggers:
// - webdriver, webdriverio
// - @wdio/applitools-service, @wdio/browserstack-service, @wdio/devtools-service, @wdio/sauce-service
// - @wdio/mocha-framework, @wdio/jasmine-framework
// - @wdio/local-runner
// - @wdio/sumologic-reporter
// - @wdio/cli, @wdio/config, @wdio/utils
// Level of logging verbosity: trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent
// logLevels: {
//     webdriver: 'info',
//     '@wdio/applitools-service': 'info'
// },
//
// If you only want to run your tests until a specific amount of tests have failed use
// bail (default is 0 - don't bail, run all tests).
bail: 0,
//
// Set a base URL in order to shorten url command calls. If your `url` parameter starts
// with `/`, the base url gets prepended, not including the path portion of your baseUrl.
// If your `url` parameter starts without a scheme or `/` (like `some/path`), the base url
// gets prepended directly.
baseUrl: 'https://test.com',
//
// Default timeout for all waitFor* commands.
waitforTimeout: 10000,
//
// Default timeout in milliseconds for request
// if browser driver or grid doesn't send response
connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,
//
// Default request retries count
connectionRetryCount: 3,
//
// Test runner services
// Services take over a specific job you don't want to take care of. They enhance
// your test setup with almost no effort. Unlike plugins, they don't add new
// commands. Instead, they hook themselves up into the test process.
services: [
    ['selenium-standalone', { drivers: { firefox: 'latest', chrome: 'latest', chromiumedge: 'latest' } }]
],


// Framework you want to run your specs with.
// The following are supported: Mocha, Jasmine, and Cucumber
// see also: https://webdriver.io/docs/frameworks
//
// Make sure you have the wdio adapter package for the specific framework installed
// before running any tests.
framework: 'cucumber',
//
// The number of times to retry the entire specfile when it fails as a whole
// specFileRetries: 1,
//
// Delay in seconds between the spec file retry attempts
// specFileRetriesDelay: 0,
//
// Whether or not retried specfiles should be retried immediately or deferred to the end of the queue
// specFileRetriesDeferred: false,
//
// Test reporter for stdout.
// The only one supported by default is 'dot'
// see also: https://webdriver.io/docs/dot-reporter
reporters: ['spec'],


//
// If you are using Cucumber you need to specify the location of your step definitions.
cucumberOpts: {
    // <string[]> (file/dir) require files before executing features
    require: ['./stepdefinations/given.js', './stepdefinations/when.js', './stepdefinations/then.js'],
    // <boolean> show full backtrace for errors
    backtrace: false,
    // <string[]> ("extension:module") require files with the given EXTENSION after requiring MODULE (repeatable)
    requireModule: ['@babel/register'],
    // <boolean> invoke formatters without executing steps
    dryRun: false,
    // <boolean> abort the run on first failure
    failFast: false,
    // <string[]> (type[:path]) specify the output format, optionally supply PATH to redirect formatter output (repeatable)
    format: ['pretty'],
    // <boolean> hide step definition snippets for pending steps
    snippets: true,
    // <boolean> hide source uris
    source: true,
    // <string[]> (name) specify the profile to use
    profile: [],
    // <boolean> fail if there are any undefined or pending steps
    strict: false,
    // <string> (expression) only execute the features or scenarios with tags matching the expression
    tagExpression: '',
    // <number> timeout for step definitions
    timeout: 60000,
    // <boolean> Enable this config to treat undefined definitions as warnings.
    ignoreUndefinedDefinitions: false
},

reporters: [
    'spec',

    ['allure', {
        outputDir: './reports/allure-results',
        disableWebdriverStepsReporting: true,
        disableWebdriverScreenshotsReporting: true,
    }],

    ['json', {
      outputDir: './reports/json-results'
      }],

    ['junit', {
      outputDir: './reports/junit-results',
      outputFileFormat: function(options) {
            return `results-${options.cid}.${options.capabilities}.xml`
        }
    }],

  ],

//
// =====
// Hooks
// =====
// WebdriverIO provides several hooks you can use to interfere with the test process in order to enhance
// it and to build services around it. You can either apply a single function or an array of
// methods to it. If one of them returns with a promise, WebdriverIO will wait until that promise got
// resolved to continue.
/**
 * Gets executed once before all workers get launched.
 * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
 * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
 */
onPrepare: function (config, capabilities) {
    console.log('Test is preparing');
},
/**
 * Gets executed before a worker process is spawned and can be used to initialise specific service
 * for that worker as well as modify runtime environments in an async fashion.
 * @param  {String} cid      capability id (e.g 0-0)
 * @param  {[type]} caps     object containing capabilities for session that will be spawn in the worker
 * @param  {[type]} specs    specs to be run in the worker process
 * @param  {[type]} args     object that will be merged with the main configuration once worker is initialised
 * @param  {[type]} execArgv list of string arguments passed to the worker process
 */
// onWorkerStart: function (cid, caps, specs, args, execArgv) {
// },
/**
 * Gets executed just before initialising the webdriver session and test framework. It allows you
 * to manipulate configurations depending on the capability or spec.
 * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
 * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
 * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that are to be run
 */
// beforeSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) {
// },
/**
 * Gets executed before test execution begins. At this point you can access to all global
 * variables like `browser`. It is the perfect place to define custom commands.
 * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
 * @param {Array.<String>} specs        List of spec file paths that are to be run
 * @param {Object}         browser      instance of created browser/device session
 */
// before: function (capabilities, specs) {
// },
/**
 * Runs before a WebdriverIO command gets executed.
 * @param {String} commandName hook command name
 * @param {Array} args arguments that command would receive
 */
// beforeCommand: function (commandName, args) {
// },
/**
 * Runs before a Cucumber feature
 */
// beforeFeature: function (uri, feature) {
// },
/**
 * Runs before a Cucumber scenario
 */
// beforeScenario: function (world) {
// },
/**
 * Runs before a Cucumber step
 */
// beforeStep: function (step, context) {
// },
/**
 * Runs after a Cucumber step
 */
// afterStep: function (step, context) {
// },
/**
 * Runs after a Cucumber scenario
 */
// afterScenario: function (world) {
// },
/**
 * Runs after a Cucumber feature
 */
// afterFeature: function (uri, feature) {
// },

/**
 * Runs after a WebdriverIO command gets executed
 * @param {String} commandName hook command name
 * @param {Array} args arguments that command would receive
 * @param {Number} result 0 - command success, 1 - command error
 * @param {Object} error error object if any
 */
// afterCommand: function (commandName, args, result, error) {
// },
/**
 * Gets executed after all tests are done. You still have access to all global variables from
 * the test.
 * @param {Number} result 0 - test pass, 1 - test fail
 * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
 * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that ran
 */
// after: function (result, capabilities, specs) {
// },
/**
 * Gets executed right after terminating the webdriver session.
 * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
 * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
 * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that ran
 */
// afterSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) {
// },
/**
 * Gets executed after all workers got shut down and the process is about to exit. An error
 * thrown in the onComplete hook will result in the test run failing.
 * @param {Object} exitCode 0 - success, 1 - fail
 * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
 * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
 * @param {<Object>} results object containing test results
 */
// onComplete: function(exitCode, config, capabilities, results) {
// },
/**
* Gets executed when a refresh happens.
* @param {String} oldSessionId session ID of the old session
* @param {String} newSessionId session ID of the new session
*/
//onReload: function(oldSessionId, newSessionId) {
//}
```

}

Attaching the logs here too:

`2021-06-04T06:27:55.993Z DEBUG @wdio/config:utils: Couldn't find ts-node package, no TypeScript compiling
Execution of 1 spec files started at 2021-06-04T06:27:56.014Z

2021-06-04T06:27:56.086Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
Test is preparing

2021-06-04T06:30:48.355Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerStart hook

2021-06-04T06:30:48.359Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: run,./config/wdio.conf.js

[0-0] 2021-06-04T06:30:49.021Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run

[0-0] RUNNING in chrome - D:\webdriverIO-automation\features\logintrainer.feature

[0-0] 2021-06-04T06:30:49.974Z INFO webdriver: Initiate new session using the WebDriver protocol

I tried to comment the on prepare hook out, but still there is a onPrepare hook being run.`

This really slow the test down, appreciate if any idea on this issue.

PS: I'm using the latest webdriver-IO, nodeJS and chrome driver

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
services: [
    ['selenium-standalone', { drivers: { firefox: 'latest', chrome: 'latest', chromiumedge: 'latest' },skipSeleniumInstall:true }]
],
```

add skipSeleniumInstall:true else it will try to download the drivers each time