# How can I prevent the download of the selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar before running WebdriverIO tests?

Tags: selenium, testing, webdriver-io

I am testing GUI using Webdriver.io tools. Every time you run Webdriver tests, it tries to load selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar before starting the tests, which is very time consuming.

[image]

How to prevent Webdriver from downloading the selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar file? Or is there some other way to solve this problem?

Comment: What does your wdio.conf.js look like?

Comment: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/n-AVoAPP-JJWDQ

Comment: If I change the number on line 144 from 90,000 to 1000, the web driver crashes with an error: "ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status undefined due to TimeoutError: Timeout awaiting 'request' for 1000ms"

Comment: Is this a node project? What do your wdio dependencies in package.json look like?

It looks like your tests are erroring out but the issue you mention is that it is "time-consuming". So, are you trying to make the install work or have you already got it working?

You don't *need* the selenium standalone server to run WDIO. You can use a browser driver service. Not 100% sure if that would speed up the runtime or not though.

Comment: An error occurs because the file cannot be loaded. The tests then continue to run normally. Dependencies in package.json: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/1pIfDMRbxMU0Ew

Comment: please add the wbdriverio config and logs to question not as link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67839362/6793637